# What are 2D quaternions called (what should I search for more information)?

Tags: c#, rotation, xna, quaternions

I stumbled on a working concept for a fast rotation & orientation system today, based on a two-term quaternion that represents either a rotation about the X axis (1,0,0) in the form *w* + *ix*, a rotation about the Y axis (0,1,0) in the form *w* + *jy*, or a rotation about the Z axis (0,0,1) in the form *w* + *kz*.

They're *similar* to complex numbers, but a) are half-angled and double-sided like all quaternions (they're simply quaternions with two of three imaginary terms zeroed out), and b) represent rotations about one of three 3D axes *specifically*.

My problem and question is...I can't find any representation of such a system online and have no idea what to search for. What are these complex numbers called? Who else has done something like this before? Where can I find more information on the path I'm headed down? It seems too good to be true and I want to find the other shoe before it drops on me.

Practical example I worked out (an orientation quaternion from Tait-Bryan angles):

```
ZQuat Y, YQuat P, XQuat R; // yaw, pitch, roll
float w = Y.W * P.W;
float x = -Y.Z * P.Y;
float y = Y.W * P.Y;
float z = Y.Z * P.W;
Quaternion O; // orientation
O.W = x * R.W + w * R.X;
O.X = y * R.W + z * R.X;
O.Y = z * R.W - y * R.X;
O.Z = w * R.W - x * R.X;
```

Comment: I don't get the question. They're called quaternions, yes, and are commonly used for the purpose you describe. In the X and Y planes, obviously you have quaternions with two non-zero components only. They are still quaternions.

Comment: @Rei My question, then, is where are they used for the purpose I describe? I can't find an implementation/extension of quaternions that operates on simplified two-term quaternions, much less "XQuats," "YQuats," and "ZQuats" that are specific to an axis. (edit: I'm mainly asking to make things easier on myself. There's a lot of operator overloading and method writing ahead on this path, and I want to avoid any pitfalls and see if it's been done before.)

Comment: Yes, they can be used but of course in 2D you use 2D vectors and 2x2 matrices, which can be seen as cases of quaternions and 4x4 matrices.

Comment: Quaternions are used (among other reasons) to avoid the problems of Euler angles. If you split a single rotation in three quaternions as you described, you end up with basically the same representation and the same problems. I strongly recommend not to use this representation. Unless your scenario could also be well-represented by Euler angles. But then just use the angles.

Answer (score 0):

Quaternions in 2D would degenerate to just being a single component being no diferrent than an rotation angle. That's propably why you do not find anything. With quaternions you do f.e. not have the problem of gimbal lock, appearing when two rotation axes align because of rotation order. In normal 2D space you do not have more than a single rotation axis, so it has neither order (how do you sort a single element) and there are no axes to align. The lack of rotation axes in 2D is because you get a rotation axis when being perpendicular to two other axes.

This gives 3 axes for 3D:

> ```
> X&Y=>Z
> X&Z=>Y
> Y&Z=>X
> ```

But only one for 2D:

> ```
> X&Y=>Z
> ```